# Publish/Subscribe pattern for a curses based Python application?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a python script that works like a server; it runs continuously, and prints various output to the shell/log files.

I want to create an **optional** `npycurses` frontend for it.

What I would like is for the server to run in the background, and for the frontend to connect to it, with the server pushing realtime updates out that the frontend is subscribed to (as opposed to the frontend polling the server).

I could probably achieve something like this with https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/ - but I really want something simple that can all run on my localhost.

What's the best approach?

Comment: Did you already consider the Pubsub feature of redis? https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Comment: Is there a lighter way that doesn't involve installing another application?